# BigQuery SQL: select struct as single record, not array of records

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I want to create a RECORD as the outcome of a select in BigQuery standard SQL.

If I run this SQL snippet,

```
WITH 
mock_data AS (
    SELECT 'foo1' as foo, 'bar1' as bar, 'bla1' as bla UNION ALL
    SELECT 'foo2' as foo, 'bar2' as bar, 'bla2' as bla
)
SELECT 
    *,
    STRUCT(
        m.foo as foo,
        m.bar as bar
    ) as foobar
FROM mock_data m
```

the output of foobar is an array of records, not a single record. [image: output of the query]

How could I have the `foobar` column be a single record and not an array of records?
Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a single record - not an array

You can clearly see this in JSON Tab

[image]

Also you can go to "Job Information" Tab

[image]

and click on "Temporary Table" to see the schema of output

[image]

In the BigQuery IDE that I am using - it is even more visible

[image]

Comment: Interesting! Thanks a lot Michail I got confused by how it is displayed in the results, with "row 1" as if there could be various rows. Solved!

Answer (score 1):

The [`UNNEST` operator](https://httpshttps://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#unnest_operator) flattens arrays into rows, i.e. it breaks an array into several rows. `STRUCT` elements get broken down into multi-column records, which is what I think you require. Try something like this out:

```sql
SELECT
   *,
   UNNEST(
      STRUCT(
        m.foo as foo,
        m.bar as bar
      ) as foobar
   )
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Blend3rman! Your code seems to be wrong syntactically, if I try the following adaptation it complains about UNNEST needing to be done on an array and not a single struct:

```WITH 
mock_data AS (
    SELECT 'foo1' as foo, 'bar1' as bar, 'bla1' as bla UNION ALL
    SELECT 'foo2' as foo, 'bar2' as bar, 'bla2' as bla
)
SELECT 
    *,
   (SELECT * FROM UNNEST(STRUCT(
        m.foo as foo,
        m.bar as bar
    ))) as foobar
FROM mock_data m```